# Show that $\mu=E(x)=6$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, statistics

Use the fact that

$ \ f_x=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\Bigl(\left (\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^x-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^x \Bigr)$

where $f(x) := \frac {f_{x-1}}{2^x}$.

Show that $\mu=E(x)=6$.

My attempt:

$E(x)= \sum_{x=2}^ \infty xf(x)=\sum_{x=2}^\infty x \frac {f_{x-1}}{2^x}=\sum_{x=2}^\infty \frac{x}{\sqrt5 \cdot 2^x}\Bigl(\left (\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^{x-1}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2} \right)^{x-1} \Bigr)$

I have no idea how to calculate this sum. Try to use the geometric series theorem, but don't know how to put it in the way of $\sum _{x=2}^ \infty a \cdot r^{n-1}= \frac {a}{1-r}$ if $|r| \lt 1 $. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what's the range of x?

Comment: from 2 to infinity

Comment: The RHS of $f_x$ has nothing to do with $x$?

Comment: that $f_x$ defines Fibonacci numbers as $x$ goes from 2 to infinity

Comment: The notation $x$ is very confusing. Since it means an integer, $n$ or $m$ would be much better.

Comment: I'm curious about how this question is related to `statistics`.

Comment: Also, your definition of $E(x)$ is problematic. You probably mean $E(X)$ and the Fibonacci sequence gives the pmf of $X$.

Comment: It deals with the expected value, which is the same as finding the mean. So, it is part of statistics. My definition of the expected value based on my textbook.

Comment: no. the p.m.f is the f(x), in which I defined above.

Comment: i think this will be in use:[link] (http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/16-6/finkelstein.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking up where you left off:

$\displaystyle \sum_{x=2}^\infty \frac{x}{\sqrt5 \cdot 2^x}\left(\left (\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}^2 \right)^2 \right)$

$\displaystyle \dfrac {1}{\sqrt 5}\left(\left (\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}^2 \right)^2 \right) \sum_{x=2}^\infty \frac{x}{2^x}$

Let's just ignore the constant outside and just work on the sum 
$\displaystyle \sum_{x=2}^\infty \frac{x}{2^x} = \sum_{x=2}^\infty x \left(\dfrac 12 \right)^x $

As you know, $\displaystyle \sum_{x=0}^\infty r^x = \dfrac {1}{1-r}$ for $|r|<1$.

Taking the derivative of both sides, we get

$\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^\infty x r^{x-1} = -\dfrac {1}{(1-r)^2}$ for $|r|<1$

This look almost like, but not quite the sum we wish to evaluate. Let's multiply both sides by $r$:

$r\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^\infty x r^{x-1} = -\dfrac {r}{(1-r)^2}$ for $|r|<1$

$\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^\infty x r^{x} = -\dfrac {r}{(1-r)^2}$ for $|r|<1$

If we put $r = \dfrac 12$ we get the desired sum, but with the index a little bit off.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Lily You're welcome

Comment: If you were asked to calculate $ E(x^2)$, would you take the second derivative?

Comment: @Lily Taking another derivative of $\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^\infty x r^{x-1}$ would give you $\displaystyle \sum_{x=2}^\infty x(x-1) r^{x-2} $. I would take the first derivative of $\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^\infty x r^{x} $ and multiply by $r$ again.

Comment: @Lily We are differentiating with respect to $r$, not $x$. It would be $\dfrac {d}{dr} \left [  \displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^\infty x r^{x} \right ] =   \displaystyle \sum_{x=2}^\infty x^2 r^{x-1}$

Comment: @Lily Also, even if we were differentiating with respect to $x$ yourresult of  $r^x +x^2 \cdot r^{r-1}$ would be incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. So that summation equals to $\frac {1+r}{(1-r)^3}$, right?

Comment: @Lily Yes that's correct.